# How to change the column names of a mapping table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am creating an Entity Framework 6 database using the Empty EF Designer Model.

My issue can be duplicated as follows. I have two tables and a many to many association between them.

[image: EF 6 Model]

When I generate the database, it creates a third mapping table, which I expect. However, the names of the columns are unexpected.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordWordType] (
    [Words_WordId] int  NOT NULL,
    [WordTypes_WordTypeId] int  NOT NULL
);
```

Notice that the mapping table has column names that are somewhat redundant and long. The column names include the table name, which is redundant, followed by an underscore, followed by the Key column name.

```
WordWordType
- Words_WordId
- WordTypes_WordTypeId
```

I am hoping EF 6 has a way to create the mapping table with column names that don't include the table name and underscore. I need the table to look as follows.

```
WordWordType
- WordId
- WordTypeId
```

Answer (score 0):

In Code First you can use fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Word>()
      .HasMany(w => w.WordTypes)
      .WithMany(wt => wt.Words)
      .Map(x =>
           {
              x.ToTable("WordWordType"); 
              x.MapLeftKey("WordId");
              x.MapRightKey("WordTypeId");
           });
```

but since you are using model first I think the only way is to change T4 file which is responsible for generating SQL script. You can find it in `Database Script Generation` section in your model properties.

**Update**

see [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures1T4TemplateDebuggingInVisualStudio2012.aspx) for debugging T4.

the `SSDLToSQL10.tt` contains two main section for this, one is `Creating all tables` on line 150 and another one is `Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints` on line 196, they enumerate on `Store.GetAllEntitySets()` and `Store.GetAllAssociationSets()` and creating tables and foreign keys in database, debug the T4 file and see where your mapping table is created, I suspect it is in `Store.GetAllEntitySets()`, then change the generation the way you want.

Comment: Thanks. This info I have found in searching. Unfortunately, I am trying to find how to do this in Model First.

Comment: Are you familiar with T4?

Comment: No. I am researching it now. My next guess is to copy SSDLToSQL10.tt to SSDLToSQL10-custom.tt and modify it. Then use it. However, I can't find where to modify it.

Comment: I've updated the answer, this is just a guideline not the exact answer, if you manage to solve the problem please share so others can use your knowledge later. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you already have the table name in your primary key column name, which is - in my opinion - a redundant information.

If your name your primary key columns simply `Id`, then EF will automatically name your columns `Word_Id` and `WordType_Id`.

Comment: Not quite. It is Words_Id and WordTypes_Id. Notice the plural. Also, I had just Id. Then I read that suggested EF6 might not put the table name if I used this convention. It didn't work. Regardless of whether I use Id or WordId in the Word table, I need the WordToWordTypeMap column to be WordId and WordTypeId.